# Remotely check on an app's status in pm2 from a website?

Tags: node.js, monitoring, pm2

I'd like to check the status of an app registered with pm2 remotely such that other web-based monitoring services can give us a notification when something breaks.

Are there any options available to remotely check the status of a process in pm2 remotely? One possibility is to have a web script remotely `eval()` the `pm2 status` command and look for certain keywords, and make that script accessible on the web for the notification tool. This doesn't seem ideal, though, as we're using an `eval` command and maybe a regex of that output just to see what is going on.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple web interface for PM2.
You can simply start a websocket connection to `/logs` and get your application(s) stats updates such as `status`, `uptime`, `cpu usage`, `memory usage`, `restarts` in realtime.Feel free to use and contribute. Cheers!

https://github.com/doorbash/pm2-web

[image: pm2-web]

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use [keymetrics](https://keymetrics.io). It's free to monitor upto 4 processes(great for development and side projects), easy to link an instance/server but quickly turns out to be very expensive when you scale up.

You could always try switching to other alternatives like [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) or [pm2-gui](https://github.com/Tjatse/pm2-gui).

Comment: Thanks for the link to Keymetrics. A problem with Keymetrics, though, is that it wouldn't fit in to existing infrastructure that checks for uptime on various pages. The idea was to have some page we could hit and gather the stats from pm2. Looks like just doing the `eval` call may be the best way still.

Comment: I find pm2 horribly overpriced. When you have more than 24 processes running, you are forced into the custom "Enterprise" plan. Simple alerting is also only available on Enterprise. And there doesn't appear to be a way to check out any of the Plus or Enterprise features in a free trial before buying. As such, I find it hard to recommend keymetrics, even though it's probably the best solution out there. The other two projects mentioned are either dead/unmaintained or nowhere near offering the same capabilities.